# Python. Проброс значения функции внутри класса

Tags: python-3.x

Такой вопрос: есть значение, которое вычисляется в функции внутри класса.
Никак не могу сообразить, как мне пробросить вычисленное значение в другую функцию.

Для примера того, что я пыталась сделать, вот такой код:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''

    @staticmethod
    def inp():
        name = input()
        return name

    @staticmethod
    def pr():
        print(name)


random_name = Test()
random_name.inp()
random_name.pr()
```

@staticmethod я использую т.к. мне нужен такой подход для автотестов.

Буду благодарна за дельный совет, как пробросить значение, вычесленное в функции один в функцию два. ❤️

Answer (score 2):

Что-то масло масленное получилось.
Вас не смущает ошибка?

> NameError: name 'name' is not defined

Тут два варианта:

1. Либо использовать атрибут, и тогда надо прокидывать `self` везде:

   ```
   class Test:
       def __init__(self):
           self.name = ''

       def inp(self):
           self.name = input()

       def pr(self):
           print(self.name)
   ```

   В таком случае значение будет пробрасываться между функциями в рамках экземпляра класса, никакой статики.
2. Либо использовать классовую переменную:

   ```
   class Test:
       name = ''

       @staticmethod
       def inp():
           Test.name = input()

       @staticmethod
       def pr():
           print(Test.name)
   ```

   Так методы останутся статичными, и никакого `self` не надо, переменная сохранится в классе, а не в экземпляре.